# URL is showing MVC controller name twice

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working with .net mvc and angular js.

HomeController

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In angular controller there is a service to get all the item details

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetItemDetails()
    {
         // return item list
    }
```

If I run the solution without opening HomeController in visual studio I found 404 error saying that resource is not found.
One more thing I have noticed in network is the called URL is "/Home/Home/GetItemDetails".

But when I open HomeController  in visual studio everything will be working fine.
 How it is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http.get("Home/GetItemDetails") this is the URL I had used to call controller method.
I missed slash in this

So the solution is  $http.get("/Home/GetItemDetails")

Thank you.

Comment: How to achieve it in JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your routing values and the URL you called are one and the same.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

For this, the URL looks like /Home/Index

Verify the URL you are using in Angular and you may be adding the controller name twice somewhere.